# Blocking visitors that access by server IP address

Tags: apache-httpd, access-control

My Apache Server IP address is 192.168.1.100 and the Domain Name is `test.local`.

- If a user types in the URL, say "http://test.local", then they should be allowed.
- If a user tries to access "http://192.168.1.100" then they should be denied.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is [name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html), so something  along these lines might get you started, I believe:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location />
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  </Location>
  # other configuration for default host...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # This is the one you would like visible
  ServerName test.local
  <Location />
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

(I'm in a bit of a hurry, so there might even by typos in there, sorry.)

Comment: I suggest adding an explicit [`_default_` VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#default) entry.